# Checking if update query affected rows perl

Tags: sql, postgresql, perl

I have an "UPDATE" query and I want to check if this query has affected any rows and if it has I would like to send an email to myself. I'm not really experienced with perl or sql. (I'm using postgresql).

**EDIT:** I know that UPDATE returns "count" which tells how many rows if any have been updated, but I still don't know how to get to it.

The code looks like this:

```
my $updateQuery - //UPDATE query 
if(//updateQuery has effected rows){
     //send mail
}else
     //do nothing
```

The problem is I don't know what to put into the if, what flag should I set? Is there any easy check that answers "has effected rows"?

Comment: May I suggest some useful reading? http://search.cpan.org/~rudy/DBD-Pg/Pg.pm ...

Comment: I assume you're using DBI to do this (and, if not, why not?) You'll probably want to use the `do()` method to run the query. This returns the number of rows affected. See [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#do) for more details.

Comment: @DaveCross Yes, I'm using DBI. the variable "updateQuery" contains an update query where I update some stuff. I read that "UPDATE" returns 0 or 1 (I think)  upon completion. The only problem I  have is how to extract that number so I can use it inside the if statement. So when updated changed some rows it will send mail if not then it will not. Also is there a way to extracted from the query directly without doing any additional stuff? Sorry if I'm being too vague /:.

Comment: Like I said, you'll want to look at `do()`. See the documentation I referred to.

Comment: If you're only running the query once, you can use [`do()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#do) as Dave Cross suggested. If you're running the same query multiple times, you should use [`prepare()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#prepare) and [`execute()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#execute). For non-SELECT queries, `execute()` will return the number of rows affected, just like `do()`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Maybe to clarify, I'm only looking for a simple true or false to use in the if statement. When I compere the variable !"updateQuery" == 0 in the if statement like so `if(!updateQuery == 0)` it doesn't go into the if. (Does UPDATE only return 0?). I want to use it like this because the mail is sent regardless of if the columns are updated or not. Sorry if I for sounding rude.

Comment: @Username Don't worry, you don't sound rude at all. There is no `UPDATE` method in DBI, and in the code you've shown, `$updateQuery` is just a scalar variable; you can't tell just from looking at a string how many rows will be updated, so you actually have to execute the query. When you execute the query with `do()` or `execute()`, the return value will be the number of rows affected. See Dave Cross's answer for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcut version using `do()`

```
my $update_query = '...';

my $ret = $dbh->do($update_query);

if ($ret) {
  if ($ret eq '0E0') {
    # no rows updated
  } else {
    # rows updated
  }
} else {
  # error
}
```

Full `prepare()`/`execute()` version.

```
my $update_query = '...';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($update_query);

my $ret = $sth->execute;

if ($ret) {
  if ($ret eq '0E0') {
    # no rows updated
  } else {
    # rows updated
  }
} else {
  # error
}
```